# Live stream using Youtube's Livestreaming API to someone else's channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I tried youtube's watchme app for live streaming and I understand the code fairly. In my use case the user needs to be able to live stream to another channel. I understand there is a need of Stream key here, but I need a rough guidance on where I need to change in the code. Any hints or a rough idea would do too. I just need headstart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [Youtube WatchMe app for Android](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme), it will create live events on your Youtube account. If you want the user to type a Stream Key from a Live stream issued from another Youtube account you will have to create a function similar to the [`startStreaming`](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/watchme/MainActivity.java#L99-L113) method :

```java
public void startStreaming(EventData event) {

    //the event is already started on your external live stream
    //String broadcastId = event.getId();
    //new StartEventTask().execute(broadcastId);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            StreamerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(YouTubeApi.RTMP_URL_KEY, event.getIngestionAddress());

    // we don't need this since it's only used to end the live event
    intent.putExtra(YouTubeApi.BROADCAST_ID_KEY, "");

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_STREAMER);
}
```

Note that broadcast id is sent to `StreamerActivity` in order to be able to finish the event ([`endEvent`](https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme/blob/dce98c275bdf3cda5996f8590bdfedd36a9b673f/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/watchme/StreamerActivity.java#L258-L267)) which you won't be able to do using an external live stream.

`event.getIngestionAddress()` is the Stream Key url eg :

```
rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<Stream key>
```

So you can create a method like the following :

```java
public void startStreaming(String streamKey) {

    String url = "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/" + streamKey;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StreamerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(YouTubeApi.RTMP_URL_KEY, url);
    intent.putExtra(YouTubeApi.BROADCAST_ID_KEY, "");

    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_STREAMER);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me give this a try ASAP. If this works then you are God, man I have been wall-banging since morning.

Comment: So, I believe we can not create or end broadcasts belonging to someone else's channel, we can only stream to that broadcast. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you can only access the Youtube API for the account logged in your app (and from which user has accepted "manage my Youtube account" scope)